# Unable to process Jar entry for log4j-core-2.17.0.jar

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

When i'm trying to update **log4j-1.2.16.jar** to **log4j-core-2.17.0.jar** i'm getting below exception.Can anyone help me on this exception?

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/PathWithAttributes.class] from Jar [jar:file:/application/xyz/apache-tomcat-7.0.54_BB/webapps/xyz/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.17.0.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowMethodParameters(Utility.java:797)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Attribute.readAttribute(Attribute.java:171)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FieldOrMethod.<init>(FieldOrMethod.java:57)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Method.<init>(Method.java:71)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:267)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2058)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1934)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1900)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1885)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1898)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The JAR file you donwloaded must be corrupted.

Comment: Please let me check that case, will update you.